Issue with snowflake-snowpark-python and Azure function
I’m attempting to publish an Azure Function using Python 3.9.12 and include the snowflake-snowpark-python library. However, as soon as I import the library and deploy the Azure Function, it no longer appears in the Function App portal. (The function shows up as soon as I publish the code without importing the snowflake-snowpark-python library).
Here are the import lines
from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import when_matched, when_not_matched,col

Here are the library versions I am using:
aiohappyeyeballs==2.4.4
aiohttp==3.11.10
aiosignal==1.3.1
asn1crypto==1.5.1
async-timeout==5.0.1
attrs==24.2.0
azure-functions==1.21.3
azure-functions-durable==1.2.10
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
boto3==1.35.77
botocore==1.35.77
certifi==2024.8.30
cffi==1.17.1
charset-normalizer==3.4.0
cloudpickle==2.0.0
cryptography==44.0.0
filelock==3.16.1
frozenlist==1.5.0
furl==2.1.3
greenlet==3.1.1
idna==3.10
jmespath==1.0.1
lxml==5.3.0
multidict==6.1.0
numpy==1.25.2
orderedmultidict==1.0.1
packaging==24.2
pandas==2.0.3
platformdirs==4.3.6
propcache==0.2.1
protobuf==5.29.1
pyarrow==18.1.0
pycparser==2.22
PyJWT==2.10.1
pyodbc==4.0.39
pyOpenSSL==24.3.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.2
PyYAML==6.0.2
redshift-connector==2.1.4
requests==2.32.3
s3transfer==0.10.4
scramp==1.4.5
six==1.17.0
snowflake-connector-python==3.12.3
snowflake-snowpark-python==1.5.0
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.5.1
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.6
SQLAlchemy==1.4.7
tomlkit==0.13.2
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.2
tzlocal==5.2
urllib3==1.26.20
yarl==1.18.3

I have also tested multiple versions of the snowflake-snowpark-python library, but all of them result in the same issue. I am using 1.5.0 because snowflake-snowpark-python's official documentation recommends that version.
Is there a version I can use which would allow me to publish the Azure function as expected?
P.S. – There are no warnings or errors during the publishing process. Is there a way to debug why the function isn't appearing in the portal, even though the deployment shows no errors?
My function code:
# Register this blueprint by adding the following line of code 
# to your entry point file.  
# app.register_functions(blueprint) 
# 
# Please refer to https://aka.ms/azure-functions-python-blueprints


import azure.functions as func
import logging
from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
import os
import pandas as pd
import redshift_connector as connector
import json
from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import when_matched, when_not_matched,col


blueprint = func.Blueprint()


@blueprint.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

SOLUTION:
The issue was due to a library called cryptography, which is a dependency of snowflake.snowpark.
To fix it I reverted the library version to 43.0.3.
You can follow the issue here.

How are you deploying the function to azure? Also did you check the logstream?

Install the package snowflake-snowpark-python version 1.25.0 and cloudpickle version 2.2.1.
I have updated the requirements.txt as below:
aiohappyeyeballs==2.4.4
aiohttp==3.11.10
aiosignal==1.3.1
asn1crypto==1.5.1
async-timeout==5.0.1
attrs==24.2.0
azure-functions==1.21.3
azure-functions-durable==1.2.10
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
boto3==1.35.77
botocore==1.35.77
certifi==2024.8.30
cffi==1.17.1
charset-normalizer==3.4.0
cloudpickle==2.2.1
cryptography==44.0.0
filelock==3.16.1
frozenlist==1.5.0
furl==2.1.3
greenlet==3.1.1
idna==3.10
jmespath==1.0.1
lxml==5.3.0
multidict==6.1.0
numpy==1.25.2
orderedmultidict==1.0.1
packaging==24.2
pandas==2.0.3
platformdirs==4.3.6
propcache==0.2.1
protobuf==5.29.1
pyarrow==18.1.0
pycparser==2.22
PyJWT==2.10.1
pyodbc==4.0.39
pyOpenSSL==24.3.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.2
PyYAML==6.0.2
redshift-connector==2.1.4
requests==2.32.3
s3transfer==0.10.4
scramp==1.4.5
six==1.17.0
snowflake-connector-python==3.12.3
snowflake-snowpark-python==1.25.0
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.5.1
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.6
SQLAlchemy==1.4.7
tomlkit==0.13.2
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.2
tzlocal==5.2
urllib3==1.26.20
yarl==1.18.3

Code Snippet:
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from snowflake.snowpark.session import Session
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import when_matched, when_not_matched,col

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

Deployed the function to Azure:
Command: func azure functionapp publish rkfn

Getting site publishing info...
[2024-12-10T06:21:04.832Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING app setting.
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE app setting.
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Uploading 114.44 MB [#############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id '4c0c74d4-c'.
//Removed few logs
[06:25:18+0000] Installing collected packages: six, pycparser, urllib3, python-dateutil, jmespath, cffi, propcache, multidict, idna, frozenlist, cryptography, charset-normalizer, certifi, botocore, yarl, typing-extensions, tomlkit, soupsieve, sortedcontainers, s3transfer, requests, pytz, pyOpenSSL, PyJWT, platformdirs, packaging, orderedmultidict, greenlet, filelock, attrs, asn1crypto, aiosignal, aiohappyeyeballs, wheel, tzlocal, tzdata, SQLAlchemy, snowflake-connector-python, setuptools, scramp, PyYAML, protobuf, numpy, lxml, furl, cloudpickle, boto3, beautifulsoup4, azure-functions, aiohttp, snowflake-sqlalchemy, snowflake-snowpark-python, redshift-connector, pyodbc, pyarrow, pandas, azure-functions-durable, async-timeout
[06:25:30+0000] Successfully installed PyJWT-2.10.1 PyYAML-6.0.2 SQLAlchemy-1.4.7 aiohappyeyeballs-2.4.4 aiohttp-3.11.10 aiosignal-1.3.1 asn1crypto-1.5.1 async-timeout-5.0.1 attrs-24.2.0 azure-functions-1.21.3 azure-functions-durable-1.2.10 beautifulsoup4-4.12.3 boto3-1.35.77 botocore-1.35.77 certifi-2024.8.30 cffi-1.17.1 charset-normalizer-3.4.0 cloudpickle-2.2.1 cryptography-44.0.0 filelock-3.16.1 frozenlist-1.5.0 furl-2.1.3 greenlet-3.1.1 idna-3.10 jmespath-1.0.1 lxml-5.3.0 multidict-6.1.0 numpy-1.25.2 orderedmultidict-1.0.1 packaging-24.2 pandas-2.0.3 platformdirs-4.3.6 propcache-0.2.1 protobuf-5.29.1 pyOpenSSL-24.3.0 pyarrow-18.1.0 pycparser-2.22 pyodbc-4.0.39 python-dateutil-2.9.0.post0 pytz-2024.2 redshift-connector-2.1.4 requests-2.32.3 s3transfer-0.10.4 scramp-1.4.5 setuptools-75.6.0 six-1.17.0 snowflake-connector-python-3.12.3 snowflake-snowpark-python-1.25.0 snowflake-sqlalchemy-1.5.1 sortedcontainers-2.4.0 soupsieve-2.6 tomlkit-0.13.2 typing-extensions-4.12.2 tzdata-2024.2 tzlocal-5.2 urllib3-1.26.20 wheel-0.45.1 yarl-1.18.3
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 24.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.10/bin/python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
Done in 11 sec(s).
//Removed few logs
Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
[2024-12-10T06:27:45.864Z] Syncing triggers...
Functions in rkfn:
    http_trigger - [httpTrigger]
        Invoke url: https://XXXXfn.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger

Portal:
Able to see the function trigger in Azure function App in portal.


I updated the requirements, but I am still facing the same issue. I am using Azure Devops to publish the function using a YAML file. The publishing logs show no error, and for some reason there is no logs tab in the deployment center in azure function.

Can you share your function code? Also try deploying using IDE or CLI and check if you face the same issue.

My function code is exactly the same as yours.  I have edited the question and added my function code.
I created a new function app as well with App service plan to be able to see the deployment logs, but they also don't show any error.

I have tried with your code and faced the same issue. Couldn't sync the trigger image.

Change blueprint = func.Blueprint to blueprint = func.FunctionApp() in function_app.py

After updating the code as mentioned in the above comment, able to deploy the function and see the trigger. Refer image.

I already have a FunctionApp(), I am using that to run this blueprint file. I figured out the issue.
Thank you for your help.

The issue was due to a library called cryptography, which is a dependency of snowflake.snowpark.
To fix it I reverted the library version to 43.0.3.
You can follow the issue here.
